# CKEditor not changing size of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor

I have installed CKEditor into my rails app. Inside the editor, when I choose an image after browsing the server, I try and change the size of the image with the `height` and `width` options given.

[image]

When the show page is displayed with the server image, it is the original image size when I initially downloaded.

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Blog Show Page</h1>

  <h3><%= @blog.title %></h3>
  <br>
  <%= simple_format(@blog.body) %>
  <br>
  Keyword: <%= @blog.keyword %>
  <br>
  <br>
  Published on: <%= unsanitize_date(@blog.publish_date.to_s) %>
  <br>
```

Can anybody shed some light on to why the editor will not allow re-sizing of images?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `simple_format`. Replace with `raw` and now the image sizing should work.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do that CKEditor just add `style` attribute to `<img/>` tag. Image resizing is done on server, not in client. If you want to do it, just define multiple versions in `CkeditorPictureUploader` class. See [ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem.